# PFQuery returning object multiple times in UICollectionview

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I created a UICollection view, and I made it so that the collectionviewcells display thumbnail images. There are four objects on the back end. The collection view retrievs four objects, however, it usually retrieves one or more objects more than once, instead of querying and showing each of the four objects only once. Im not sure what the issue could be. Here is my method for querying the data, and displaying it in the collection view:

```
-(void)queryForTable {
    NSLog(@"Querying");
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VideoApp"];
    NSString * author = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FBName"];
    [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:author];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];



        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d objects", objects.count);
                userVideosArray = objects;
                [self.collectionView reloadData];

   /*             for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"video_thumbnail"];
                    [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            NSLog(@"Fetching image");
                            //[userVideosArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                            videos = objects;
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                        }
                    }];
                } */
            }
        }];
    //return videos;


}
```

here is the method for creating the cell:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"initializing collection view");
    //CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell * cell = (CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewcellCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // NSLog(@"%@", videos);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   // imageView.image = [videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];


    //NSString *tmpObjectId = userVideosArray[indexPath.item];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VideoApp"];
    NSString * author = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"FBName"];
    [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:author];
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    NSLog(@"AUTHOR IS: %@", author);
    NSLog(@"number of objects in query: %i", [query countObjects]);

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        //tagTxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"video_tag"]];
        //handleTxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@", [object objectForKey:@"author"]];
        // locTxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@",[object objectForKey:@"video_location"]];
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"video_thumbnail"];
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
                if (!error) {
                    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    //[self.collectionView reloadData];

                }
            }];

        }

    }];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should never fetch and/or create the datasource from within a view's delegate method. The view should only act as a reflection of the modal part it represents.**

The problem that you are facing is that, the image is fetched in background and when the query was fetched by the cell you might see the cell at position 1. But as the collection view reuses the cell, it will use the same cell again as you scroll down. And the query that was fetched earlier might finally execute at this point; ie. the image will be assigned to the cell. So eventhough a new request is send at this point, it takes time to show again.

Another thing is that it's not good to add subviews to the cell within the 'cellForItem..' method as the same cell will be added with more subviews again and again.

As a hack for both the above you could remove all the subviews of the cell each time it is dequeued. So that eventhough the previous query will be executed, the image won't be assigned.

Comment: How should I go about creating the datasource? Should i create it within the viewDidLoad? If thats the case I'm not sure how because I can't access the "cell" property from that method

Comment: yes you could.. store the values (in your case as it is just an image) in an array.. And populate this array with values in viewDidLoad. And each time when the array count increases ( on retrieving the image object ), reload the collection view.

In the collection view's delegate method take the count the array's count  and use the array's object in the 'cellForItem' method